# 10 questions about active directory :)

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, internal-dns

I am setting up a network with about 20 computers, 10 servers and 3 printers. But there are quite a few things Im not sure about. So here goes...

1. I have read that it's good practice to have two domain controllers on a network. Is this still true for a small network that won't have much impact if the server is down?
2. Can active directory be used to deploy Windows assuming the PC'S support network boot?
3. Are users files stored locally or on the domain controller? And is there a feature that allows you to centralise, say the documents folder on a file server?
4. Is there an option that allows you to let the user login if the server is down?
5. Does the server CPU power matter (within reason) or will a slower CPU increase login times?
6. Can software be installed on all computers remotely if it has an automatic installer or script?
7. Is there anything that allows you to have groups or roles to give users different privileges?
8. Does Active Directory have any sort of "web api"  so that it can be tied with a separate web based user management system?
9. Can all or most Active Directory settings and features be accessed via CMD or Power Shell?
10. Can windows licencing be manged as per computer (not a group licence) as in each copy of Windows was purchased separately with its own key?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While these are reasonable questions, they are not being asked in a way that fits the format of this site.  Also, you don't appear to have done any research on your own.  Many of these questions can easily be answered by a quick google search.  Also many of them are very broad, and couldn't really be answered here.

Comment: @zoredache I have done a lot of research. But the Microsoft website does not tell you these things unless you know the correct terms used and names. A general search has mixed and unclear answers

Comment: I've voted to close your question because it is too broad. However, as a courtesy, I am answering all ten of your questions here: 1. No. 2. You can do this in your environment, with or without AD, but it will take time, research, and testing to set up. 3. Yes. 4. Yes. 5. Don't worry about CPU performance. 6. Yes. 7. Yes. 8. Read about LDAP. 9. Yes. 10. Yes, but read up about CALs.

Comment: @Skyhawk 8. could also be yes, but learn about ADFS.

Comment: @skyhawk Thanks :) nice summary. If you add it as a answer I will mark it correct.

Comment: @Zoredache Do I understand correctly that ADFS can be used say, for a website login page that relies on AD for its users?

Comment: Bloody cheek. I ask three questions total. with no downvotes. Than one question gets 3 downvotes for no good reason and I get blocked.
And what the heck does "on hold" mean?

Comment: ADFS supports SAML, which is an authentication protocol available via an API.  There are several services like Google Apps that allow federate authentication via SAML.

Comment: Oh, and 'On hold' is a temporary closed state for questions.  Some questions could be fixed with some editing and get re-opened.  A question that is on hold, will eventually be considered closed.

Comment: Well It has an answer so _that_  will eventually make it considered closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you don't mind an upper bound of ~99% availability, one domain controller is fine. What will your company do on the days when the server is down? What is your backup and disaster recovery strategy?
2. You can do this in your environment, with or without AD, but it will take time, research, and testing to set up.
3. Yes.
4. Yes.
5. Don't worry about CPU performance.
6. Yes.
7. Yes.
8. Yes. Read about LDAP and ADFS.
9. Yes.
10. Yes, but read up about CALs.